# How to efficiently check if name exists in database

Tags: python, django, filter

I would like to efficiently check if a certain name is shared by any other name of the items of a shop

Of course I could just cycle through all of the items in the shop and compare their names, but I'm sure that there is a contains() sort of method, just for the name. Perhaps using filter()? But how? There are too many broad answers and I can't figure it out for my unique problem

```py
models.py
...
class Item(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
...

class Shop(models.Model):
    shop_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    items = models.ManyToManyField('Product')
...

views.py
...
def check(name):
    if name in Shop.items.filter(name)
        # do something

...
```

My code doesn't seem to pick up that there are any items with the same name in the shop (even though I can prove that there is)

Comment: try `Shop.objects.filter(items__item_name=name).exists()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just write an [exists](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists) query, instead of searching in whole list. Using exists is much more efficient. Ofical document also specifies this:

> Note: Don’t use this if all you want to do is determine if at least one result exists. It’s more efficient to use exists().

So your query would become something like:

```
Item.objects.filter(item_name__iexact=name).exists()
```

Comment: Thanks! that is EXACTLY what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def check(name):
    query_set = Shop.objects.fileter(items__item_name__icontains=name)
        # do something
```

Comment: And then what do I do with the query_set? How do I interact with it to get what I need?

Comment: Query_set is the collection of Shop objects which matches the item_name. You can loop through the query_set and do what you want.

Here an example that print Shop_name whose item_name matches.

for shops in query_set:
    print(shops.shop_name)